# Need help converting a curl request to java request

Tags: java, http, curl, post

I have a certain curl request as given below -

```
curl -POST -H 'access-key: <apikey>' -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{
"item": "electricity",
"region": "india",
"unit": "kWh",
"quantity": 1.564}' 'https://www.carbonhub.xyz/v1/emissions'`
```

I tried making a java counterpart for the same , this is what I have come up till now -

```
package org.kodejava.example.httpclient;    
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class getEmissions {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://www.carbonhub.xyz/v1/emissions");

        List<NameValuePair> data = new ArrayList<>(4); 
        data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("item", "electricity"));
        data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("region", "india"));
        data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("unit", "kWh"));
        data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("quantity", 1.564));

        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
            post.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            // use your api key
            post.setHeader("access-key","<apikey>");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            // Print out the response message
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know how to fix this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `UrlEncodedFormEntity` is for encoding Content Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You need to convert the `data` to JSON, preferably using a JSON library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are sending data in `POST` request is not as per specified `curl` command.

You should first make a `JSON` string for your input. There are various libraries you can use for this purpose like `Jackson`, `JSON-java`, `Gson` etc. or you can manually construct `JSON` string (not recommended) and then you should send `JSON` string as data in `POST` request.

Below is one way to manually constructing `JSON` string and then sending it as `POST` data -

```
package org.kodejava.example.httpclient;    

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.IOException;

public class getEmissions {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://www.carbonhub.xyz/v1/emissions");

        StringBuilder requestData = new StringBuilder("'{");
        requestData.append("\"item\"").append(':').append("\"electricity\"").append(',');
        requestData.append("\"region\"").append(':').append("\"india\"").append(',');
        requestData.append("\"unit\"").append(':').append("\"kWh\"").append(',');
        requestData.append("\"quantity\"").append(':').append("1.564");
        requestData.append("}'");

        StringEntity requestDataEntity = new StringEntity(requestData.toString(),ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        try {
            post.setEntity(requestData);
            // use your api key
            post.setHeader("access-key","<apikey>");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            // Print out the response message
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```